# How to get the innerHtml, including the tag, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Sorry, if the title is too obscure ;D.

Actually the problem is, lets say i am  this code.

```
<span id="spanIDxx" style="blah-blah">
   <tag1>code here </tag2> sample text 
   <tag2>code here </tag2> html aass hhddll
   sample text
</span>
```

Now if i will use the code.

```
jQuery("#spanIDxx").html();
```

then it will return just the innerHTML excluding  `<span id="spanIDxx" style="blah-blah">`
but i want something which can return the innerHTML including the specified element.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will create a new `div` and append a clone of your element to that `div`. The new `div` never gets inserted into the DOM, so it doesn't affect your page.

```
var theResult = $('<div />').append($("#spanIDxx").clone()).html();

alert( theResult );
```

If you need to use this frequently, and don't want to bother with adding yet another plugin, just make it into a function:

```
function htmlInclusive(elem) { return $('<div />').append($(elem).clone()).html(); }

alert( htmlInclusive("#spanIDxx") );
```

Or extend jQuery yourself:

```
$.fn.htmlInclusive = function() { return $('<div />').append($(this).clone()).html(); }

alert( $("#spanIDxx").htmlInclusive() );
```

Comment: Some chap wrote a plugin called `outerHTML` to do this: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/. Someone else extended the plugin to allow replacement: http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the node to a new empty  node, ask for new .parent() and then its .html()

Answer (score 1):

[Clone](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/clone) might be useful to you. I don't believe you actually need to do anything with the clone/s.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this myself but looks like it may be of use:

http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/

demo here: http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/outerhtml/demo.html