# How to get the content and the container tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to get a row

```
<tr class="phoneNumber">
   ABC...
</tr>
```

and when i do $(".phoneNumber").html(), it returns `ABC...`

Is there a way to get

```
<tr class="phoneNumber">
   ABC...
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the innerHtml, including the tag, using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319213/how-to-get-the-innerhtml-including-the-tag-using-jquery)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html has the answer you're after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
  }
})(jQuery);

$('.phoneNumber').outerHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `outerHTML`:

```
$('.phoneNumber')[0].outerHTML
```

Or, if compatibility is important to you, use one of the extensions listed at [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2419749/707111).