# Get HTML String for jQuery and/or DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I think I've read through the complete [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) and looked at jQuery objects and simple DOM elements in the debugger to check what methods they actually have at runtime, but for the life of me, I can't find a way to get the html string that represents the contents of a jQuery object or a DOM Node. Am I missing something?

jQuery objects have the method `html()`, DOM elements have the property `innerHTML` but both only give the inner html of the object. So if I have HTML like this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

And I use jQuery doing something like this `var $div = $body.find("div")` and I then call `$div.html()` the returned string is `"<p>Hello World!</p>"`. But I'm looking for a way to make it return `"<div><p>Hello World!</p></div>"` (I don't care about the whitespace).

What am I doing wrong? It can't be that difficult to get the html representation of these objects, can it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the innerHtml, including the tag, using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319213/how-to-get-the-innerhtml-including-the-tag-using-jquery)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try the dom property `.outerHTML`

Comment: I remembered this as a non-standard IE specific thing, but it seems to be [widely adopted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML) by now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the '.outerHTML' property.  This is how it would look using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/MHvmm/

```
$('div')[0].outerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by enclosing your desired object in another object, and the fetching the innerHTML.
It is explained in much more detail here:
[How do you convert a jQuery object into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string)