# How do I extract a HTML string from my jQuery selection?

Tags: jquery

My HTML code is constructed in such a way that it is in following format :

```
var s = $('<input type="date" id="date-value"/>');
```

**I want to extract the html inside my jQuery selection, as a separate element:**

```
 <input type="date" id="date-value"/>
```

I tried various inbuilt methods like `s.text()`, `s.innerHTML` etc, but they didn't work.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fkgaqtb2/

Comment: I fail to understand what you are wanting? You are already creating the new element with your `append` statement (on your fiddle)

Comment: @EdCottrell Because it doesn't work. But true, the better question is _why_?

Comment: Not working. returns a empty value.

Comment: @JClaspill I am just appending to see whether s is valid or not. But my main intention is to extarct the HTML inside the element.

Comment: for the value inside the input just use s.val()

Comment: @Tom s.val() is not working

Comment: @JClaspill s.html returns a Jquery function, but not the raw HTML inside the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new element from the selector, use jQuery's [.clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function.
`alert(s.clone().prop('outerHTML'));`

That will output the string it looks like you're trying to get in your fiddle.

In any case, if you just want a string representation of the element, remember that `s` is a selector, so you'll need jQuery's [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.
You want:
`s.prop('outerHTML')`.

FYI, this version of the question is similar to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/how-do-you-convert-a-jquery-object-into-a-string).
Rememeber that HTML elements (not jQuery selections, that's why we need `prop`) have an [`outerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466776/get-html-string-for-jquery-and-or-dom-object) too, not just `innerHTML`!

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be better to mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: I sadly don't know how, or don't have the rep/permissions yet. Care to provide a link that explains how to do so? Thanks!

Comment: You can click the "flag" option on the question > go to "a duplicate..." > put in the link to the duplicate question > click "vote to close".

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary `div`, then clone your element and append to it:

```
alert($('<div>').append(s.clone()).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the outer html, you can use:

```
var s = $('<input type="date" id="date-value"/>');
$('<div>').append(s.clone()).html();
```

Or if you need it often, you can add a new method:

```
$.fn.outerHtml=function(){
    return $('<div>').append(this.clone()).html();
}
```

And then you can just use: `s.outerHtml();`